# Write this dot product as matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this expression :
    $$ (a-b)⋅(c-d) $$

And I need to write this as product of some matrix M with matrix $\begin{bmatrix}c\\d\end{bmatrix} $, so basically: $$ M * \begin{bmatrix}c\\d\end{bmatrix}$$ Are there any rules for dot product I could use to solve this?

Edit: a, b, c and d are all vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From dimensional considerations, $M$ should be a $1\times2n$-matrix, where $n$ is the dimension of the vectors $a,b,c,d$.

Then the matrix
$$
M:=\begin{bmatrix}(a-b)^T&(b-a)^T\end{bmatrix}
$$
should work, where the transpose means to put the vector horizontally.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I separated the vectors into individual component and came to the same result but wasn't completely sure it was right. Is there an easier way to derive something like this than the way I did it?

Comment: I first determined the dimension of the matrix, and then tried to fill out the components. I guess this is what you did. I think for this kind of problems, to consider block matrices might be of some help.

Comment: Although not what was asked:  $$\left\| \begin{array}{cc} a-b & 0 \\ 0 & c-d \end{array} \right\| $$ where the notation means *determinant*.

Comment: How did you determine the dimensions of the matrix? I  wrote the whole dot product as linear combination and only then was able to determine the dimensions.

Comment: @LennyWhite Because the dot-product gives a $1\times1$-matrix, and $\begin{bmatrix}c\\d\end{bmatrix}$ is of dimension $2n\times1$.

Comment: Oh right, thanks!